# Dynamic Ranking based on date and key

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

This is my sample input data table:

```
entry_id entry_date company_id objective_title objective_status key                   objective_rank
1        2024-03-01 company_1  objective_1     Completed        company_1_objective_1 1
2        2024-12-30 company_1  objective_1     In Progress      company_1_objective_1 2
3        2024-01-02 company_2  objective_2     Not Started      company_2_objective_2 1
4        2023-11-10 company_3  objective_3     Completed        company_3_objective_3 1
```

As you can see, I've already created there a a calculated column for ranking with the following DAX formula:

```
objective_rank = 
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            table_1,
            table_1[key] = EARLIER(table_1[key])
        ),
        table_1[entry_date],
        ,
        DESC
    )
```

And this gave me the correct results when trying to see Count of Key per latest objective status for all dates (rank = 1):

```
objective_status count_key
Not Started      1
In Progress      0
Completed        2
```

Now I'd like to have a slicer that would allow the user to select specific date range (based on entry_date).

So, if the entry_date would be e.g. < 2023-12-31 then I'd like to see the following output:

```
objective_status count_key
Not Started      0
In Progress      1
Completed        1
```

because although objective_1 "In Progress" it's not the latest overall it is the latest for a given date range.

How to achieve that?

I have tried to use replies to similar issues on Microsoft Fabric Community but they didn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: When you say date is it related to the entrydate?

Comment: Yes, I've meant entry_date. I've edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sample data is incorrect - I have changed the date on the second row to make your question make sense. To get a working solution, follow these steps:

table_1:

[image]

Create a date table and relationship:

```
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

[image]

Create two measures:

```
objective_rank = 
VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE(table_1[key])
RETURN
VAR r = 
    RANKX( FILTER( ALLSELECTED(table_1), table_1[key] = x), CALCULATE( MIN( table_1[entry_date])), , DESC)

RETURN   IF(NOT ISEMPTY(table_1)  , r)


My Count = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(table_1), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table_1),  [objective_rank] = 1), table_1[objective_status] = SELECTEDVALUE(table_1[objective_status]))+0
```

Add a slicer using your date table:

[image]

Add a count table:

[image]

Add a master table:

[image]

Results with nothing selected:

[image]

Results with 31st December 2023:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that calculated columns are computed at refresh so they are not dynamic with respect to slicers: your column "objective_rank" cannot give you rank 1 based on slicer filter context.

Like davidebacci, I've also considered that the date for row 2 was supposed to be 2023-12-30 (and not 2024-12-30).
Considering that:

- your date slicer refers to a table "Calendar",
- you want to take into account all dates lower than or equal to the selected date,
- you have a dim table "status_table" for statuses (that you'll use in the report),

I've created a measure that directly provides the expected result (without any intermediate measure; tempTable provides the latest status for every key based on the max date you've selected).

```
count_key2 = 
    SUMX(status_table, 
        VAR myStatus = status_table[objective_status]
        VAR maxCalendarDate = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        VAR tempTable =
            CALCULATETABLE (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    VALUES ( table_1[key] ),
                    "Latest status",
                    VAR latestDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( table_1[entry_date] ), 'Calendar'[Date] <= maxCalendarDate )
                    RETURN CALCULATE ( VALUES ( table_1[objective_status] ), table_1[entry_date] = latestDate )
                ),
                ALL ( status_table[objective_status] ),
                ALL ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
            )
        RETURN
            COUNTAX (
                FILTER (
                    tempTable,
                    [Latest status] = myStatus
                ),
                [Latest status]
            )
    )
```

I've built it such as totals will work too (=> SUMX).